# Plotting walking trails on a map without a GPS device

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I want to mark some walking trails on a map and share them with friends. I don't have any GPS devices so I will be drawing them manually.

Since this may take some time, I would prefer that they will be in a format that I can export later.

Is there a web app can I use to plot these tracks without needing to own or have a GPS locator?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Maps to plot trails.  Check out [this link](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=23523) if you don't know how to use the My Maps feature of Google Maps.

To export, you can get the KML by clicking the "View in Google Earth" button on your map and save the KML data.

Another easy method to export your maps is to put them in a Google Fusion table, by using this utility:
http://maps-data-liberation.appspot.com/maps

This will ask you to authenticate your Google Maps and [Google Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/fusiontables) accounts, but once you do, you can pick which maps to transfer to Fusion tables, or just download the KML file.

Once your map data is in a Fusion Table, you can click the "Notes" button for each trail under the "Geometry" column to view the GPS data.

Before Google Map Maker officially closed on March 31, 2017, you could also use [Google MapMaker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker) to make your trails available to everyone on Google Maps.  Many of the features of Google MapMaker are now integrated directly in Google Maps.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [MapMyFitness](http://mapmyfitness.com)

[image: MapMyFitness]

Comment: This looks good. Routes can be exported to GPX and KML. Lots of sharing options. I like how routes can be tagged (surface, contour, surroundings, etc). It generates detailed elevation data.